# homomorphism keeps the unit and commutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R,S$ be a rings and let $\varphi:R\to S$ be a rings homomorphism on $S$. Prove or disprove with counter example:
>
> A. if $R$ is a commutative ring then $S$ is commutative
>
> B. if $R$ has a unit then $S$ has a unit.

*Attempt:*

A. Take $r_1,r_2\in R$ then $\varphi(r_1\cdot r_2)=\color{blue}{\varphi(r_1)\varphi(r_2)}=\varphi(r_2\cdot r_1)=\color{blue}{\varphi(r_2)\varphi(r_1)}\implies S$ commutative.

B. No, let $\varphi:\mathbb Z\to 2\mathbb Z$ there is a unit at $\mathbb Z$ but not in $2\mathbb Z$

Comment: Is there an error in your title "comotativicy"?  (If you mean commutativity, you have the correct spelling in your question box).

Comment: Can you edit please? my english is not the best

Comment: What is the definition of a ring homomorphism in your world? In mine, any ring homomorphism must send 1 in R to 1 in S.

Comment: For B you should use $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$, $\varphi(x)=(x,0)$.

Comment: @Justin Often, one requires $1$ to go to $1$ in the category of homomorphisms of *rings with identity,* but it isn't always required in the category of rings (since many rings don't have identities).

Comment: @Michael Burr Yes, I am aware of this. Consider that S has no identity, then 1 must be sent to something 2-idepmotent or zero, else the map is not well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

- For $A$, this only works for elements in the image of $\varphi$.  What if $S$ has more elements than are images of $\varphi$?  As an example, consider the map 
  $$
  \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow M_{2,2}
  $$
  the map from the integers to $2\times 2$ matrices where $a\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$.
- For $B$, what is your map from $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}$?  Is it the multiplication by $2$ map?  If so $2=\varphi(1)=\varphi(1\cdot 1)=\varphi(1)\cdot\varphi(1)=2\cdot 2=4$.  So, the map is not well-defined.  What if you consider the zero map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow2\mathbb{Z}$?  (Or the example of @egreg in the comments above).
- As a side note to $B$, consider the map
  $$
  \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\operatorname{Diag}_{2,2}
  $$
  the map from the integers to $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices where $a\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  In this case, both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\operatorname{Diag}_{2,2}$ have identities, but the map does not take the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the identity of $\operatorname{Diag}_{2,2}$.

Comment: For A, this type of matrices is also commutative and also $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Error404 Just the image is commutative.  The set of *all* $2\times 2$ matrices is not commutative.  The codomain is much larger than the image.

Comment: I got it for A. for B I meant if there is a unit necessary (not must be the same unit as in S) @Michael Burr

Comment: No, a unit is not necessary, either use the zero map or the example that @egreg gives in the comments.

Comment: if the homomorphism was onto?, for B

Comment: Both $A$ and $B$ are true if the homomorphism is onto - try to prove it and ask a new question with your attempt, if you wish.

Comment: I will post tomorrow morning another similar qoustion